# C#, Valid ModelState fails .isValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

C# valid ModelState fails .isValid

### Search Controller

```
//
// GET: /Search/Create
public ActionResult Create()  { return View();  } 

//
// POST: /Search/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Search search)
{
    search.Created = DateTime.Now;

    search.SearchSet = "test data";
    search.URLParameter = 1432567389;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Searchs.Add(search);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(search); 
}
```

### Search Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TalentProfile.Models
{
    public class Search
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int URLParameter { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Client must be 50 characters or less")]
        public string Client { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText), StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be {1} characters or less")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SearchSet { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I run in debug all the fields in the class are properly set but it fails `ModelState.IsValid`. If I drill into the `ModelState.IsValid` it is false. Drilling down further I find the error “The SearchSet field is required”.
The `SearchSet` field is properly set to “test data”. If I remove the `ModelState.IsValid` check the save to the database succeeds.

Why am I getting the “field is required” error if the field contains valid data.

### Talent Controller

```
//
// GET: /Talent/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Talent/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Talent talent)
{
    talent.Modified = talent.Created = DateTime.Now;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Talents.Add(talent);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        CreatePhoto(talent.Id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(talent);
}
```

### Updated: Search Controller and Create View

```
//
// GET: /Search/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
    Search search = new Search();
    search.SearchSet = "test Data";
    return View(search);
}

//
// POST: /Search/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Search search)
{
    search.Created = DateTime.Now;

    search.URLParameter = 1435267836;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Searchs.Add(search);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(search);
}
```

In view put: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SearchSet)`

Comment: +1 for the namespace TalentProfile.Models :)  Sounds like you're doing a website for a fashion show...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note here:

1) putting a Required attribute on value types is pointless.  Value types must always contain a value, they can't be null.. thus Required will always pass for them.

In particular, DateTime is a value type.  Also, your UrlParameter is an int, which is also a value type.  it will always contain at least a default value.  Required is redundant.

2) As others have said, the ModelState is only set during databinding.  data binding only occurs before the method is called, or when you call UpdateModel or TryUpdateModel.  Regardless of whether or not you have other errors, you cannot update the model and expect the ModelState to reflect the changes if you have not called UpdateModel or TryUpdateModel.

3) Client is set as required, but you don't seem to be setting it.  So if you set Client and SearchSet then do TryUpdateModel(search) it should be valid.

4) Talent works because, like in Search, `talent.Modified` and `talent.Created` are `DateTime`s and are non-nullable, thus they will never fail validation, even if you don't set a value (see for yourself, remove the assignment and see how it still validates).  Any other required fields you may have on Talent are likely also value types.

Comment: Yes, Man I came to the same conclusion after my last post. When the form is posted back to the POST action a Search object is created.  Created and URLParameter are DateTime and int fields are non-nullable and are set to 01/01/0001 and 0 by default.  SearchSet is a string whose default is null, thus the ModelState fails on SearchSet.  Drilling down into ModleState shows that it only checks the string fields (Client, Notes and SearchSet), Client and Notes are set in the view.  This is why you can set the DateTime and int but not the string fields in the POST action.

Comment: Passing the view a Search object with the SearchSet field set to a non-null value in the GET action and then exposing SearchSet with a @Html.HiddenFor  resolves the problem.  See updated post with the revised code.  You make some good points on the Required attribute, I will rethink those, especially since I will be setting the value of SearchSet, URLParameter and Created in code.

Answer (score 1):

Use TryUpdateModel(search); before your ModelState check. So it should be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Search search)
{
    search.Created = DateTime.Now;
    search.SearchSet = "test data";
    search.URLParameter = 1432567389;

    TryUpdateModel(search);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Searchs.Add(search);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(search); 
}
```

Comment: TryUpdateModel(search); didn't make any difference.  The .isValid still fails.  See my other comments.  The same code works in another controller.

Answer (score 1):

The ModelState is resolved during model binding, so the `Search` object passed to `Create` has to have the `SearchSet` value set. I.e. setting `SearchSet` in the controller is not going to make the model valid if the value was empty during model binding.

Answer (score -1):

The MVC runtime would've already validated the model before executing your action, and it hasn't revalidated it after you set the parameters locally in the action.

So the idea is you do a post with the search model in it, for example from an html form, and MVC checks validity BEFORE going into your action, so you don't have to :)

Comment: See comment to friism.  My view is a Html form for both the Talent and the Search Create views.  The Talent works and the Search fails.  Do you have a suggested code for the Search action?

Comment: HELLO MODERATOR,  friism, Mystere Man, and appclay all contributed to the answer.  Why can I only mark one of them as the answer,  all three are part of the answer.